# What's better practice? Protected / getter?

Tags: c++, oop

If I have a class that inherits from another, and only this class has to use a certain variable, which is better practice? To have said variable be 'protected' in the base class, or have it private and give it a protected getter?

I've heard conflicting things. My teachers told me to always use getters, while other people have told me that using getters at any level reveals bad program design. What's the real answer? I feel like both are illogical extremes.

Also, if getters and setters are bad program design, why is this?

Are there any resources that will teach me more about how to structure my code?

Comment: If only the derived type makes use of the variable, why is it defined in the base class?

Comment: the base class needs to use it too, I meant the only other thing that uses it is the derived class. my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need (or anticipate you will need in the future) to do anything else other than just reading a value? For example: assertions, locking or making the read polymorphic?

- If no, use the field.
- If yes, use the getter.

Whether you use `protected` or not is completely orthogonal to that.

*BTW, managed languages such as C# and Java often require the presence of getters, where "logically" just the ordinary fields would suffice, because their UI design (and other) tools were implemented to use [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29#Qt.2FC.2B.2B) that way. So the practice of excessively using getters seems to have "rubbed off" the C++, despite the lack of reflection or such tools in C++.*

Comment: Sorry to call you out on this, but your assertion of the reasons for C#/Java "often requiring the presence" is plain baloney.  It is a recommended best practice that rubbed off on C++.  Any time you ever expose a field outside a class, you've by-definition bound implementation details of that class to other classes.  Wrapping with getters/setters is sometimes used as a band-aid for this, but sometimes it is the best decision, too.  There are frameworks that rely on this behavior (e.g. to do dynamic proxies), but this is not the *origin* of the practice.

Comment: +1, this is how I usually decide if I need to use setters/getters or not. I use getters/setters when a class must check the new set value or trigger an event upon value change.

Comment: C++ comes at this from the other angle: It says - don't use what you don't need.  That's why I might tightly couple classes (expose a field) in C++ that I wouldn't in a million years in C#/Java.  I'd think about it hard, though, as it is a *perf*-based optimization that would have to trump a design decision.  You know what they say about premature optimization...

Comment: Merlyn: getters vs a  field is not a "perf-based optimization". an inline function is as fast as a macro, getters can additionally keep const-correctness and have thee possibility to pass references around, which is potentially more useful than direct member access.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham For example, visual form designer in WinForms and WPF (for the most part) both require properties and cannot work with fields. And as for "exposing implementation details", this *can* also be true for methods, especially in the context of inheritance. It all depends on context and I would always be suspicious of hard-and-fast rules. If your "context" is "frameworks that rely on this behavior", than this is exactly the same argument as I made for C# and Java.

Comment: @rubenvb: I'm not sure you're arguing against my point.  I didn't say accessor methods weren't useful.  I was explaining that the advice given here is a C++ way of thinking.  It is the same reason that in C++ (and C#) methods aren't virtual by default.  You don't pay for what you don't use - that's the phrase I was looking for :)

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: The frameworks aren't the point.  That's not the origin of the design practice.  Them relying on it doesn't make it the origin either.  Fields *are* implementation details.  That isn't a rule, it's just plain truth.  And we agree that simply stuffing them in accessor methods often doesn't fix the problem.  I meant to imply that by saying it was a band-aid.

Comment: @rubenvb: You can have const-correctness with exposed fields in C++. Either make the field `const`, or have a `const&` to your class-instance.

Comment: phresnel: that is not nearly as flexible and "const-correct" as the hybrid form getters could provide you with, expecially when you purposely omit getters or setters for some data members.

Answer (score 2):

`protected` is closer to `public` than `private`. People can create a derived class, access and change the protected members and use their derived instance as an instance of the base class. You can make your decision based on that. If you want a data member to be read-only for the outside world, you need a getter and there is no way around that. A protected getter (and maybe setter) can also work.

Another thing to note is that setters can act as a gateway to your data. They can be used to validate ranges and throw exceptions when needed. Take this into consideration as well.

Also, since you said that it is for use by a certain derived class, you might want to make that class `friend`. This may or may not be a good idea, you should carefully evaluate pros and cons.

I don't think that getters and setters are generally bad design. I'm sure they can be abused, as almost any idiom or pattern. Generalizing is never a good idea.<sup>(1)</sup>

<sup>(1) Yeah.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Your protected and public interface (classes, members, fields) are things that you need to keep stable. Every time you change your protected and public interface, you have the potential to break any code that depends on it.

This might be one line of your own code that you break. It might be hundreds of classes in your own codebase. If you shipped your code somewhat publicly, then you might break thousands of lines of code from hundreds of programmers you've never heard of and will never meet.

Sometimes this break is necessary and good. Sometimes it could have been avoided with a little foresight. Getting into the habit of understanding and considering your *reasons for change* is the core to good design.

> if getters and setters are bad program design, why is this?

Getters and Setters give you only a small amount of encapsulation. You still aren't hiding much from users. They still know there's a field of that type in your code (or at least know you're pretending that that there is), and they depend on it being there. If you changed the implementation of your class in such a way that made that field unnecessary, you couldn't remove the getter/setter unless you were willing to break all dependent code. If you tried to avoid the break, you'd have to make those accessors still work and make logical sense, which might be difficult.

Sometimes exposing a field (or a Getter/Setter) makes sense, even in high level code. If that field is important to access, and would never have a good reason to change name or type (from the view of a programmer using your code), then it might be fine and good and best to expose it in some way.

Sometimes wrapping fields in a Getter/Setter makes sense. If you have Getters/Setters, it can be easier to add logging, bounds checking, thread locks/semaphores, and debugger breakpoints. It is also easier in C++ to define an abstract interface that requires a Getter/Setter to be present than it is to define an interface that requires a field to be present.

Sometimes directly exposing a field, and not using getters/setters makes sense. Sometimes "classes" made entirely of fields makes sense (consider using a `struct` instead). This is going to be most common in very low level code (such as code that pulls data out of a file), or inside the implementation of another class (such as in the implementation of an algorithm). Often you'll hide these classes inside other classes, so users of your code never see them.

> My teachers told me to always use getters, while other people have told me that using getters at any level reveals bad program design. What's the real answer? I feel like both are illogical extremes.

Blanket statements often have truth to them, but truth is seldom binary.

Get in the habit of asking "*why?*". Get in the habit of judging truth for yourself, and judging situations within their own context. Sometimes what is "always best" is not actually best, or even desirable at all, in a specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

What are classes.  Collections of *data* or collections of *behaviors*?

Of course they're both.  But let's contrast how fields and accessor methods (getters and setters) enable you to work with data and behaviors.

**Fields**

- Are data
- You can't alter their behavior without altering dependent classes (unless they're pointers to [abstract base classes](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/abcs.html))
- They can be directly accessed with operators, so can be used inline in expressions.
- You can't get as clever with their noun-based names.  They usually won't be tied to beahvior.

**Accessor methods**

- Are behaviors
- You can change them without having to alter dependent classes (assuming you've kept the same [contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract))
- You cannot access them directly with operators, so can't be used directly in as many expressions (without some work).
- You can do [Method Chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) with them.
- You can get as clever as you want with their verb-based names (`Get`, `Create`, `Find`, etc).  They define a behavior.

Tangent: Method chaining is neat, because it lets you create something called [a "Fluent Interface"](http://ayende.com/blog/2639/fluent-interfaces-method-chaining).

**Encapsulation**

Whatever you do, you should remember your OO principles.  Don't violate your [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

If you write a class that is suppose to encapsulate its whole behavior, yet exposes a field, you've broken your encapsulation.  If you've written a class that stores data, and has convenient assignment/data-generation patterns that happen to map well to methods on that class, then you haven't broken your encapsulation.

Which case is true for your class depends on the [level of abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_abstraction) the class is operating at.

**When to use each**

They both make sense to use in certain contexts.

It makes sense at lower levels of code to work more closely and intimately with data.  In these cases you should use the most performant and most data-tied syntax you can.  *Use fields*.

It makes sense at higher levels of code to work more closely and intimately with behaviors.  In these cases you should use the most flexible and most behavior-tied syntax you can.  *Use accessors*.  Or, often, *don't use accessors*.  Use interfaces, classes, and non-accessor methods instead.

When in doubt, I opt for flexibility over performance.  It is hard to predict performance bottlenecks in whole programs by examining things at this particular level of detail.  We're really bad at it, and that is why profilers exist.  It is easier to make an accessor into a field than vice-versa.  If you're careful and lucky, you might already have your accessors inlined, which would then make it a moot point.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, getters and setters do reveal bad desing. But there is no general rule. The main reason to use getters and setters should be for debugging, so when you're accessing some base class member from a derived class, you have a point you can set a breakpoint at to intercept changes to that member.

So, you should adapt. If you plan on having 2-3 levels of inheritance, it's better to go with protected members, since there aren't that many places the member can change. If more, protected setters/getters might be a better option - you don't want to set breakpoints in every class that can possibly modify a member of the base class.

Answer (score 0):

If the member in the Base class is not required to be accessed outside the derived class then you make them `protected` in the base class. That is the purpose of `protected` access specifier.

Getter and setter methods are an explicit way of saying that this member variable is available for use and usually they should be used to expose the member to external entities. They make the intent clear, but since your variables only need to be accessed in the derived class, the `protected` access specifier already expresses the intent clearly.

Comment: If you have an inheritance hierarchy with 20 classes, using getters and setters is better - makes it easier to debug.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: A class design/Organization should indicate the intent clearly rather than be organized for ease of debugging. True,You try to make your classes good for debugging while expressing the intent of them clearly but that is not the purpose.

Comment: I hope the downvoter will enlighten us all with the reason of downvote.

Comment: I agree with you. +1 for the answer. I usually also try to avoid this, but sometimes I just prefer refactoring the code instead of setting 100's of breakpoints (sometimes a data breakpoint just doesn't cut it).